# TabView common to all activities

Tags: android, android-tablayout, tabview

I am using **tabview** in my application with which I am navigating to all modules present in my android application.

However, I am facing a problem while using it. **Tabview** is present on my launching activity, but no further. I want the tabview to be present in all activities.

How should I proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html